# Convert vb.net static method call on object

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am having more problems with my converting of vb.net to c#.net.

I have some files in vb.net that have "Option Strict Off" to allow for bad programming.  When I convert to c# I use "dynamic" until I come back and fix problems, and this works in all cases

But now I have this code:

```
Public Class ContractResults
   'Big class definition
   Public Shared Sub CleanCache()
       'Code here
   End Sub
End Class
```

And in a file with Option Strict Off:

```
Public Sub VerifyResults(result as Object)
   'Here, result is normally ContractResults
   'first it check for that then call this:
   result.CleanCache()
End Sub
```

In c# I use "dynamic", but a runtime error pops up when I call "static" method with dynamic reference.  In vb.net, I can called "shared" sub from instance, but in c# this is not allowed

Exception:
   "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException"
   "Member 'ContractTypes.ContractResults.CleanCache()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

It seems I must convert code to use actual type, but then this means much rewriting of more parts.  Is anyone able to show another way?

I want to make sure you do not think I can use

```
(result as ContractResults).CleanCache();
```

Because all types that may be passed in have "CleanCache()" method, but do not inherits from anything the same other than "Object".  There are many types (30!) that have this "static" method and so that is why it uses Option Strict Off

Comment: For 30 types's I'd just turn Option Strict On and fix it in VB. The IDE will give you warnings for each and you should be able to run through everything pretty fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx):

```
result.GetType().InvokeMember("CleanCache", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy, null, null, new object[0]);
```

*(untested*)

Comment: This work: I had to add "BindingFlags.InvokeMember".  One problem in the loop this runs in this seems to have slowing of the code, but I like it for conversion - convert bad code becomes bad converted code, in my eyes.  I would vote up but I am not good enough user.

Comment: Upvoted because this is good enough to let the OP keep working.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you have to call a static method from the class, not an instance:

```
ContractResults.CleanCache();
```

You could put your 30 types into a switch statement, but this would be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say this, but the original decision to turn Option Strict Off was a bad one.  Somehow I doubt that the code that was originally written does what you think it's doing anyway.

It's time to just go ahead and fix that problem.

Comment: I think this way too but conversion schedule is not increased for fixing old bad code.  I would still vote you up though (but I am not good enough user).